# Program runs into OutOfMemoryException on some Java versions, but not others

Tags: java, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I have a java program which uses a lot of memory. On some Java versions, it runs into OutOfMemoryExceptions and other versions it does not.

This is rather annoying because this program is run by users, and many times they don't have a Java version that works properly.

The only difference between when it works and doesn't work is the Java version.

Here are some example versions that do work: 1.8.0_111, 1.8.0_144, 1.8.0_172, and 1.8.0_181
Here are some which do not work. Java 8 231u. There are more broken versions which I cannot easily find anymore. There did not seem to be any discernable pattern to which versions did work and which did not, because that Oracle's official releases are the only versions that seem to be affected.

Using a profiler, I can see that after a while it fills up with memory and just fails to GC entirely, which is confusing because it works fine in many Java versions, and nearly all of the objects in the operations that cause this are short-lived, meaning it should get GC'd pretty easily.

Does anyone recognize this issue? How would I go about reporting it, when I barely know enough about it myself?

Comment: How much memory do you assign the application? Show the command line that you use to start the application.

Comment: It doesn't matter, I've tried a lot, I've tried a little, it happens regardless of what I specify, just if I allocate more it takes longer to run out. My normal setup doesn't involve any explicit memory size, so: `java -jar BrokenProgram.jar` basically.

Comment: There can be not sufficient memory on those machines or the default can be insufficient. Does problem happen if you run the application with 1-2GB memory?

Comment: You said you use profiler. Then you can see what data occupy the most memory and compare it to the cases when no problem occurs. What are the differences that you see?

Comment: mentallurg There isn't actually much difference, besides in one case a GC frees loads of memory, and in the other case it doesn't.

Comment: As for running it with 1-2GB of memory, the same issue occurs, it just takes longer to get there. Ie: It uses the same amount of memory, but it doesn't fill up as fast, so you can use the application for longer. Once it fills up, it's filled up though.

Comment: Can you find more information from the profiler as to what is holding the references preventing GC (a collection class, or maybe some cache instance)? Maybe this will help to identify the culprit.

Comment: An OOM error occurs when the GC can't free enough space in the heap to continue allocating. To start with, this sounds like you either have a memory leak (since the heap fills up even if you make the heap bigger) or you are not allocating enough space in the heap for the live data set.

Add the command line flag, -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal for both working and failing JDKs. This will show all settings and you can see what's different. Post that information.

Comment: https://www.diffchecker.com/tsVCpHNb Here's a diff between a working version (on the left), and a non-working version on the right. As for the profiler, I'll get information on that in a minute.

Comment: I had a quick look at the diff but it now seems to have expired. There seemed to be only four differences, mostly for RAM percentage, which I think are new between the versions you tested. Are both working and failing examples run on the same machine? I don't see how the GC could fail to collect objects that are no longer being used. I think you'll need to post GC logs to progress this (the command line flags would also be useful).

Comment: Yes, I made sure to test it on the same machine. The command to run it was provided, there were no special GC flags used, it was just java -jar Program.jar basically.